# Unable to convert the Image Url to Bitmap

Tags: android

I am fetching list of urls of images from my server and setting them in recyclerview using adapter.My requirement is to fetch the color from the image and set that color to the background of the textview,for that i am using palette library as below.But i am getting the error InputStream line unable to sort the problem,any help will be appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Album albm=malbumlist.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(albm.getProductName());
    System.out.println("Displaying the image on Recycleview");
    Glide.with(mcontext).load(albm.getImageUrl()).into(holder.thumbnail);

try {
        URL url=new URL(albm.getImageUrl());
        HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream is=connection.getInputStream();    /*  Getting error here */
        bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Palette.generateAsync(bmp, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

            int bgcolor=palette.getVibrantColor(mcontext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
            holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(bgcolor);

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this... i am using this one..if its helpful please make this answer as right.

```
String path = imageToUploadUri.getPath();
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        int bmpHeight = b.getHeight();
        int bmpWidth = b.getWidth();
        if (bmpHeight > 1500) {
            bmpHeight = bmpHeight / 4;
            bmpWidth = bmpWidth / 4;
        }
        Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, false);

        File file = new File(dir, "resize.png");
        FileOutputStream fOut;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            b.recycle();
            out.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 /**
     * load image from url and fill it in image view
     *
     * @param context
     * @param imageView   the view which will be filled by the bitmap result
     * @param imageUrl    the image link
     * @param imageHolder this drawable for place holder image
     */
    public Request loadImage(Context context, ImageView imageView, String imageUrl, @DrawableRes int imageHolder) {
        GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl(imageUrl, new LazyHeaders.Builder()
                .build());
         (imageHolder == 0)
            imageHolder = R.drawable.error_image;

        return Glide.with(context)
                .load(glideUrl)
                .error(imageHolder)
                .into(imageView).getRequest();
    }
```

here is my call to the method

```
loadImage(context, imageView,imageUrl, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with **Glide** library, here you have an example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Glide.
        with(MainActivity.this).
        load("https://YourLink").
        asBitmap().
        into(50, 50).
        get();
```

**Glide Second Example:**

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
     .load("https://YourLink")
     .asBitmap()
     .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imgView) {
      @Override
      protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
       //Your bitmap here!
        super.setResource(resource);
      }
    });
```

Another solution here is with  [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library for loading images from URL, **1)** than when image loaded successfully the library callback will return for you Bitmap of that image OR **2)** you can get only Bitmap synchronously.

Example with **Universal Image Loader** library (from library documentation):

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
```

**case1:**

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
    }
});
```

**case2:**

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap synchronously
Bitmap bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageUri);
```

Comment: when i'am using the same in my onBindviewholder method its showing the error as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: YOu must call this method on a background thread

Comment: I just edited my answer, please check Glide Second example.